# asyncTask and Context

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, android-context

This is my code a custom array adapter with this constructor

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

RowItems RowItems;
List<RowData> DataList;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewId, String[] id, RowItems rowItems, List<RowData> listData)
```

and eclipse trys to change it in my asyncTask
and this is my asyncTask

```
private  class asyncTaskProduct extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    String Url;
    String Result;
    Context MyContex;
    ProgressDialog PD; 
    String[] id;
    List<RowData> L;
    ListView lvProduct;  
    public asyncTaskProduct(String url, Context contex,ListView lv) {
        Url = url;
        MyContex = contex;
        lvProduct = lv;         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        PD = new ProgressDialog(MyContex);
        PD.setMessage("File downloading ...");
        PD.setCancelable(false);
        PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        PD.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        boolean State = false;
        getJsonResult Con = new getJsonResult();
        Result = Con.postForJson(Url);
        if (Result != null){
            State = true;
            Result = Result.substring(10, Result.length() - 1);
        }
        return State;
    };

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean State) {
        if (State) {
            for (int i = 0; i < L.size(); i++) {
                id [i]=String.valueOf(i);
            }
            lvProduct.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this,R.id.lvRow_tv_ID, id, new RowItems(), L));                 
            Toast.makeText(MyContex,Result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(MyContex,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        PD.cancel();
    }
```

my error is lvProduct.setAdpter. eclips say the constructor is undefined and try to change it to

```
CustomArrayAdapter(**asyncTaskProduct**, int textViewId, String[] id, RowItems rowItems, List<RowData> listData)
```

why change Context to asyncTaskProduct?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new CustomArrayAdapter(this,R.id.lvRow_tv_ID, id, new RowItems(), L));
```

In this statement the first parameter is not a context. It is an instance of the asynctask. You need to pass a context as parameter. So try this instead

```
new CustomArrayAdapter(yourcontext ,R.id.lvRow_tv_ID, id, new RowItems(), L));
```

now the question is what is yourContext.. If you are declaring the asynctask within a activity (or something that extends context).. then you can simply use ClassName.this.....

If not then better pass a context in the asynctask

Comment: tnx i change it to myContext .

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask is not extendeing Context such as Activity or Service does. 
The line should be:

`lvProduct.setAdapter(MyContext, new CustomArrayAdapter(this,R.id.lvRow_tv_ID, id, new RowItems(), L));`

BTW: Please start variable names for local variables with a lowercase. So `MyContext` should in fact be `myContext`. That is easier to read for others.